# Can I read the CSV file from which use first column and that column as input to spinner with no repetition?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, kivy, spinner

I have designed a Spinner GUI where I had given some set of options and that's been working but I need to know how to display the set of options by scanning values from CSV file and displaying as an options set, here I am able to display the set of values too, but not as an input for spinner. In my CSV file there are lot of repetitions of same value so I have used Counter from pandas and sorted, so that it will display only once. 
My Code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout 
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.spinner import Spinner
import pandas as pd
from collections import Counter

Builder.load_string('''
<MainScreen>:
    AnchorLayout:
        anchor_x: 'center'
        anchor_y: 'top'
        BoxLayout:
            size_hint: 1, .9
            orientation: 'vertical'
            padding: 20
            spacing: 20
            Spinner:
                id: firsto
                text: 'select'
                values: root.optionf
                on_text: root.updatesecond(firsto.text)
            Spinner:
                id: secondo
                text: 'select'
                values: root.options


''')
class MainScreen(FloatLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.buildLists()
        super(MainScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    def buildLists(self):
        df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
        saved_column = df['marks'] #you can also use df['column_name']
        a = (Counter(saved_column))
        b = (sorted(a))
        print(b)
        self.optionf = ['Select','a','b','c']
        self.options = ['Select'] 
    def updatesecond(self,text):
        if text == 'a':
            self.ids.secondo.values =['1','2']
        elif text == 'b':
            self.ids.secondo.values =['3','4']
        else:
            self.ids.secondo.values =['5','6']
    def onExit(self):
        App.get_running_app().stop()

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MainScreen()
if __name__ == "__main__": 
    TestApp().run()
```

Is it possible to scan first column of csv file. Where first column is of distance where it is repeated more than once suppose column first is of distance of 70.1,40,5.1,40.8,70.1 where 70.1 will be repeated more than once it should be displayed only once in spinner first. Instead of this line =>>>

```
self.optionf = ['Select','a','b','c']
```

values from CSV are to be displayed.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out we just need to make some changes like:

instead of this line

```
self.optionf = ['Select','a','b','c']
```

make some change as

```
self.optionf = [str(row) for row in (a)]
```

where a is the value in which values are stored of column first.